# Create an Ad hoc network over WiFi adapter (WAN)

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming, adhoc

I want to create an Ad hoc WAN network in my program, which other people can connect to as long as they are running my program.

The purpose of the network is to allow the program to exchange data when there is no internet connection/WiFi Hotspot available.

I know that it's possible to create a Hotspot which others can connect to (program called [connectify](http://www.connectify.me/)), just don't know if its possible in C#

P.S. I’m aware this question has been asked before, want to see if there have been any updates.